# Catching output of linux command in background C++ program / bash script

Tags: c++, linux, bash, background, output

I want to create c++ program or bash script that will run in background and whenever i use chosen command for example

`pwd` it will catch output of that command which will be let's say `~Desktop/folder1` and it will change that output to `You are in ~Desktop/folder1`. So the result would be that user, after using command `pwd` will see only `You are in ~Desktop/folder1`.

Pwd command is just example, i want to modify output of other commands like, ls, ps, and so on.

I want the script to work in all terminals, by that i mean if i open another terminal it would still catch output of chosen commands in that terminal.

**QUESTION:**

Is it even possible to do c++ program or bash script that would do such thing?

Comment: Of course you can do that. A kernel module can intercept all writes. The real question is; why do you want this?

Comment: @JesperJuhl, sure, but a kernel module is neither a C++ program nor a bash script.

Comment: or, if your so determined to change standard output and you're coding in c++, just re-engineer the output by modifying original src code and recompiling. You could add a flag for `--old-style` to keep the original formats. Again, the real question (which is out of scope here on S.O.) Is why would you want to do this? ;-/  Good luck?

Comment: I need to create script or program for lab in my university, that will hide one of my files from other users, and i need to hide the process that hides it, so i thought i would catch ls command and  seach for the file i need to hide and cut it out so it will not be shown, same with ps command. Yet the problem is i didn't know how and if it possible to do.

Edit: The problem with modifing original src is that `ls` command has 9000 lines of code... it's really hard to find where should i start there.

Comment: An unprivileged process cannot monitor other users' processes nor meddle with their output.  If your process can attain sufficient privilege, however, then it can simply replace the system's `ls` command.  There is no need for it to mask itself, because it exits once its work (of inserting a hacked `ls`) is done.

Comment: So if i would have root privilege (which I have), it would be possible to monitor other users processes and modify the output? And as i said modifing or replacing `ls` command seems like work for few days since it has 9000 lines of code. Unless you mean changing location of original ls command, and replacing it with my program that will run ls command with changed location?

Comment: 9000 lines is not such a large program, but you could indeed proceed as you describe.  But then you *do* need to mask the fact your hacked `ls`, etc. is running a child process.

Comment: Note also that you have couched the problem in terms of modifying the apparent behavior of specific commands.  Be aware that if you approach the problem on a command-by-command basis, then you can never completely cloak your files or processes, because one can always obtain the same information via a different route.  For example, I could write my own `ls` command that I know I can rely upon.  Only by modifying the OS itself can you completely cloak your files and processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can put shell function definitions into your bash environment configuration scripts that will have the effect you describe.  For example,

### ~/.bash_profile:

```
# ...

pwd() {
  echo You are in $(command pwd)
}

export -f pwd
```

Note the use of the `command` command to avoid recursion in shell function `pwd`.  Note also the `export -f` to export the function to child processes.  You would need a snippet like that for every command you want to override.

Depending on your system and configuration, it might be more appropriate to put them in `~/.bashrc` instead.  Or if you want it to apply to every user, then you can put those in one of the system-wide bash configuration scripts.  Note, however, that users will be able to override it.

Answer (score 1):

First, missing from your question are two important parameters. The first is which shells need to be affected by this. Is this something that is supposed to be system wide? Just one user? Just a few specific shells of a specific user?

The second missing parameter is what permissions are needed. Is this something that root is supposed to do? A non-privileged user?

Each such command you wish to intercept is a system call. Usually it's `execve`, but sometimes it's something more specific (`pwd`, for example, is, by definition, an internal shell command). Assuming you do not wish to write a kernel module (the only real way to do what you want), you will have to be a little more creative.

One option is to replace all the relevant files on the filesystem with alternative versions that do what you want. This is, of course, not possible if you are not root.

Another option that is more possible using non-privileged user is to use the `ptrace` interface to take control over the shell processes you wish to control. Be forewarned, however, that this is extremely complicated, slow in performance, and will only work on the same user as the one running the C++ program. In addition, recent kernels have further protection against simply attaching to a random process as a debugger, which means you will need to either disable it (which requires root), or run the affected shells through your program.

One program that already does something similar is <shameless_plug>`fakeroot-ng`</shameless_plug>. It sets up a debugger, and attaches to a shell in order to give it a different view of what the system is doing than the real system. You can try and hack the code to do what you want. This will probably be easier with the `multithreaded_debugger` branch, but that one is still not quite stable.

Comment: It is meant to be system wide, for all users. There is no real problem with permisson, since i have root permission, becouse I work on my own virtual machine. I already wanted to change source code of commands and replace them but problem was that simple `ls` command had 9000 lines of code and i didn't know where to change it.

Comment: @Nranir the most simple would be to modify/recompile `bash` (or whatever shell you're using)

Comment: @Nranir, if modifying 9000-line `ls` is too big a challenge for you at this point, then I think you may be in over your head on the larger project.

Answer (score 1):

You have asked the wrong question.

If what you're trying to do is to hide a set of processes and files, `/etc/ld.so.preload` is your friend.

What you need to do is to write a shared object file that re-implements `readdir` and `readdir_r` (two functions should, more or less, do it) in a way that makes sure that if someone tries to get the content of the directory where your "hidden" files are, you omit your files from the reply. At the same time, if someone tries to get the content of the /proc/ directory, you omit the directories corresponding to the processes you are trying to hide.

You can easily see whether this is the directory you wish to change the responses to by caching its inode/dev pair, and checking it. This will be resilient to renaming, symlinking etc.

Search the net for how to write an LD_PRELOAD module for instructions on how to daisy chain the functions themselves. This is **considerably** less work than modifying each and every binary out there. If you know what you are doing, this can be wrapped up in ~200 lines of code.

And now comes the kicker. You do not need to put in the LD_PRELOAD environment variable to each and every process. Simply list your shared object (after testing it with LD_PRELOAD) in `/etc/ld.so.preload`, and viola! All the processes in your system will have your libary injected to it.

Don't ignore the testing suggestion. Listing the wrong file in /etc/ld.so.preload might render your system completely unusable.

For added bonus, once you're done, install `chkrootkit` and run it, and watch as it complains that your system has been compromised. This is one of the (many) techniques used by rootkits in order to hide themselves.